# Stripe Mock returning same fingerprint hash

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

Using [RubyMock](https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock) to generate stripe cards etc..

I don't know why its always returning the same `fingerprint` hash for new cards.

[Here it gives an example of creating cards](https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock#generating-card-tokens), which is basically this:

```
card_token = StripeMock.generate_card_token(last4: rand(9999).to_s, exp_year: rand(9999)) #=> "test_tok_26"
cus = Stripe::Customer.create(source: card_token);
card = cus.sources.data.first.fingerprint #=> "wXWJT135mEK107G8"
```

And thats always `wXWJT135mEK107G8`!
Even though the input card last4 and exp_year change.

Answer (score 2):

StripeMock seems to always generate the same `fingerprint` even when the `last4` and `exp_year` are different:

```
StripeMock.start

card_token = StripeMock.generate_card_token(last4: "919#{rand 9}", exp_year: "199#{rand 9}".to_i)
cus = Stripe::Customer.create(source: card_token)
cus.sources.data.first.last4 # => "9192"
cus.sources.data.first.fingerprint # => "wXWJT135mEK107G8"

card_token = StripeMock.generate_card_token(last4: "919#{rand 9}", exp_year: "199#{rand 9}".to_i)
cus = Stripe::Customer.create(source: card_token)
cus.sources.data.first.last4 # => "9198"
cus.sources.data.first.fingerprint # => "wXWJT135mEK107G8"
```

As you can see, even I get the same fingerprint as you. In fact, StripeMock has that fingerprint value hardcoded: https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock/blob/master/lib/stripe_mock/data.rb#L228

```
def self.mock_card(params={})
  StripeMock::Util.card_merge({
    id: "test_cc_default",
    object: "card",
    last4: "4242",
    type: "Visa",
    brand: "Visa",
    funding: "credit",
    exp_month: 4,
    exp_year: 2016,
    fingerprint: "wXWJT135mEK107G8", # see?
    customer: "test_cus_default",
    country: "US",
    name: "Johnny App",
    address_line1: nil,
    address_line2: nil,
    address_city: nil,
    address_state: nil,
    address_zip: nil,
    address_country: nil,
    cvc_check: nil,
    address_line1_check: nil,
    address_zip_check: nil
  }, params)
end
```

You can just pass in your own fingerprint:

```
card_token = StripeMock.generate_card_token(fingerprint: "anything you want")
cus = Stripe::Customer.create(source: card_token)
cus.sources.data.first.fingerprint # => "anything you want"
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion!